# Featured Image field not appearing in Custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, functions

I created CPT called "Basics", then added the following code to functions.php

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');    
add_image_size('large_thumb', 900, 500, true);
add_image_size('small_thumb', 250, 250, true);
```

Featured Image Option only appear default post type, and not appeared in CPT(Basics)

Answer (score 2):

use this code to create a custom post type, 
mainly you need to include this line:

```
'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', ), 
"
```

full code to create:

```
// Register Custom Post Type
function custom_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Post Types', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Post Type', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Post Types', 'text_domain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Post Type', 'text_domain' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Item Archives', 'text_domain' ),
        'attributes'            => __( 'Item Attributes', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_items'            => __( 'View Items', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Item', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'text_domain' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', 'text_domain' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Post Type', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Post Type Description', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', ),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,        
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( 'post_type', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type', 0 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Please Use this For custom post type after register_post_type

`add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post', 'movie' ) );` // Posts and Movies

OR

```
$args = array(
        'labels'             => 'Basics',
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'Basics' ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
    );

    register_post_type( 'Basics', $args );
}
```

Full Code Here

```
function custom_theme_setup() {
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_theme_setup' );


add_action( 'init', 'codex_basic_init' );
function codex_basic_init() {
 $args = array(
        'labels'             => 'Basics',
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'basics' ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
    );

    register_post_type( 'basics', $args );}
```

Comment: tried the above code still not working

Comment: Please Provide me Your Register post type code i can View And send after Some editing.